# Location Manager Crashing when No Internet

Tags: objective-c, swift

The program runs fine when the user is connected to the internet. However, when the user is not connected, the app crashes with:

```
Error:The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'd like the catch the error before it crashes and display an alertcontroller

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            currentLoc = manager.location
            currentLocGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(location:currentLoc)
            var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant") //default: Restaurant
            query.whereKey("RestaurantLoc", nearGeoPoint:currentLocGeoPoint, withinMiles:setDistanceMiles) //filter by miles
            query.limit = 1000 //limit number of results
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if objects.isEmpty {
                    //NO RESULTS
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Unavailable Area", message:
                        "This app is not available in your area yet. We'll try our best to have it up and running as soon as possible.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                } else {
                    newArray = objects
                }
                self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
            }
        } else {
            println("error: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: At which line did the fatal error occur?

Comment: usually the error is highlighted in red. but the `if placemarks.count > 0 {` is highlighted in green. I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `if` statement. You are saying this:

```
if (error != nil) {
    println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
if placemarks.count > 0 { // ...
```

Well, there *was* an error. And you were *told* that there was an error. But you didn't listen! You didn't stop! You just go right on as if nothing had happened, and try to access the `placemarks` variable - which wasn't returned. You need to use logic here so that you *exit* if there's an error:

```
if (error != nil) {
    println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    return // go no further!
}
if placemarks.count > 0 { // ...
```

Note, however, that it would be better to check `placemarks` for `nil` *first*:

```
if placemarks == nil {
    // check error
    // return
}
if placemarks.count > 0 { // ...
```

Comment: thanks again matt. i have no idea where the return statement. i definitely had it there :(

Comment: Oh sure, that's what they all say! :)

Comment: Note my revised answer. You should be checking `placemarks` for `nil` first.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to implement `locationManager:didFailWithError` which tells the delegate when it is unable to retrieve the location. Then, you just need to handle the error with appropriate response.

For references: [CLLocationManagerDelegate apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:)

Comment: thanks @faizmokhtar. I'm going to go with Matt's answer since it points out the missing return statement.

Comment: Sure @Rachel, If Matt's  solutions works for you best then just accept it as the right answer. I'm just glad to be of help. :)